# adb on OSX Lion, but can't connect to galaxy 10.1 tab, but works fine in linux

Tags: android, macos, osx-lion, adb, galaxy-tab

I am trying to connect to a Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.2

I have seen several similar questions, but they all seemed to be related to having the device setup incorrectly. I have it set to allow "Unknown Sources" and I also have "Usb Debugging" enabled. I am able to use adb on both linux and windows machines so my tablet would seem to be correctly setup and the cable is functioning correctly.

When I plug it in to my macbook pro the tab responds with a ping to show it is aware of the connection, but when I run adb devices no device is listed.

My OSX install is fairly new and I have not installed any type of tethering software.

Any ideas?

Comment: If my solution did not work for you then let me know in case it might be something else.

Comment: If you are unable to get USB access you might consider using one of the several apps that supports ADB over Wifi.  I have personally had a fairly good experience with the free app "ADB over WiFi" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bohlool.net.wifiadb&feature=search_result:

Of course, using Wifi is slower than USB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be default adb is not setup for all device types. Please replace your current ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file with the one below, it will fix the issue. I had to do the same on my mac for the exact same device.

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
# Acer
0x0502
# AOC
0x2207
# Amazon Kindle
0x1949
# ASUS
0x0B05
# Dell
0x413C
# Foxconn
0x0489
# Fujitsu
0x04C5
# Fujitsu Toshiba
0x04C5
# Garmin-Asus
0x091E
# Google
0x18D1
# Hisense
0x109B
# HTC
0x0BB4
# Huawei
0x12D1
# K-Touch
0x24E3
# KT Tech
0x2116
# Kyocera
0x0482
# Lenevo
0x17EF
# LG
0x1004
# Motorola
0x22B8
# NEC
0x0409
# Nook
0x2080
# Nvidia
0x0955
# OTGV
0x2257
# Pantech
0x10A9
# Pegatron
0x1D4D
# Philips
0x0471
# PMC-Sierra
0x04DA
# Qualcomm
0x05C6
# SK Telesys
0x1F53
# Samsung
0x04E8
# Sharp
0x04DD
# Sony
0x054C
# Sony Ericsson
0x0FCE
# Teleepoch
0x2340
# Toshiba
0x0930
# ZTE
0x19D2
```

Comment: Thanks, it took a couple of restarts after adding but is now working well.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, though I had some extra line breaks at the end of the file, which caused adb to not start properly, but once removing them, this worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, I have just added vendor id 0x2207 for my Pipo M3 and it works like a charm (after restarting service with `adb kill-server`)

Answer (score 0):

check to see if the device shows up under USB in the System Profiler (included in OS X). If it is showing up there, but not in ADB, try adding the USB Vendor ID of the phone to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

This file can be created if it does not already exist.You will need galaxy tab 10.1 vendor id.

Please make sure the last line of the file is a Vendor ID, do not leave a blank line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
android update adb
```

The ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file is automatically updated. Restart adb or restart your machine.