# Why isn't the eclipse ADT recognizing my android device on windows?

Tags: android, usb, ddms

I've had the ADT installed for quite a while. I know I've run some apps on my device (Moto Droid4) in the past, but today the ADT doesn't appear to be acknowledging that I have it connected.

I've got the "USB debugging" checkbox on. It's connected to a USB port on the laptop. When I first connected it, the laptop brought up several dialogs asking me what I wanted to do with this, all of which I dismissed.

I tried restarting Eclipse, but it still doesn't list the device in the "Devices" list in the DDMS perspective.

I tried to follow the instructions at http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7 to see if there was an issue with my USB driver, but it's not showing my device in the devices list.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: What USB mode is your phone in when connected?  Charge only?  Mass Storage? One of the others?  I believe that can make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue numerous times. My solution every time has been to uninstall the devices using USBDeview. Run the application as administrator, and then sort by name. Find the devices corresponding to your phone, and then uninstall those devices via the right click menu.

Plug your phone back in, and tell driver search to skip obtaining from Windows Update. You should be up and running shortly.

Comment: I'm not sure what USBDeview is doing.  I'm not certain exactly what rows in the list to select, but I tried to find all the ones with "XT894".  I selected "Uninstall", but nothing really happened.  The disk light has been on solid for quite a while, but otherwise nothing is happening.

Comment: Make sure you run as Administrator (assuming you're on Windows 7). USBDeview allows you to view the devices associated with different USB Ports. Uninstalling it basically removes the driver associated with that port. Find anything that looks like it might be related to your phone. With Samsung, its things like Samsung ADB Interface.

Comment: I found one node labeled something like "Motorola ADB interface" and I uninstalled that.  Now what?

Comment: Never mind, I guess I figured it out.  I don't know why I didn't try this first, but I just went to the Moto dev site and installed the USB driver.  I had done it before.  That fixed it.  I have no idea whether this would have worked before I uninstalled that node with USBDeview.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install proper driver of your device. Only then your Eclipse can detect your device to launch you application on it.

**How can I install the driver and how can I be sure it is installed?**

1. Go to Computer(right click) -> Manage ->  Device Manager.
2. If your device is categorized in "other devices" or "portable
   devices" something is not right. Double click on the device listed
   in Device manager. Inside it check your driver details.
3. If there are no driver details shown or the button is not clickable then the driver is not installed. If it is you need to update it.
4. Windows should automatically do this for you. If not you can click on the icon when it is searching for the device driver and select "install most suitable driver automatically".
5. Either case mentioned in point 3 the end result should be that after installing your driver(mind any suitable driver if your device driver is not available). Your device should be listed under the category "Android USB Devices"
6. Now you can be sure that ADT would detect your device.

PS : I have mentioned any suitable driver because in my case I had Micromax A69(ICS) and it installed HTC driver. After this Android ADT started detecting my device. I am using Windows 7. Attaching a screen shot just for the reference -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  I have the Moto X as well and am trying to run my first "Hello World" app from Eclipse on my device.  I click "Run as > Android Application" from Eclipse with my phone in usb debug mode... and it does nothing! My device is listed under Android Device as "Motorola ADB Interface".  Is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @daniel take a look at the posts [here](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/10/troubleshooting-steps-when-eclipse-adt.html) and [here](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/11/troubleshooting-steps-when-eclipse-adt.html).

Answer (score 2):

This needs some troubleshooting first, I think:

- Have you tried rebooting the phone and PC?
- You have debugging enabled on the phone, but does it show a debugging notification when connected?
- Does the device enumerate under Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`)?
- From `cmd`, do you see it with a `adb kill-server` and `adb devices`?

Comment: * Rebooted both phone and laptop, no change.

Comment: Rebooted both phone and laptop, no change. When I connect it, I end up with two notifications, "USB debugging connected" and "Connected as a mass storage". I had originally thought that the device was not listed in Device Manager, but I now think that what does show up in that list, being "XT894" is actually the Moto Droid 4, so apparently it is showing up. In any case, it's still not listed in "adb devices", even after doing "adb kill-server".

Comment: I forgot to mention, would you try shutting down Eclipse, DDMS, and any other applications that might use the device, then try `adb kill-server` and finally `adb devices`?

If you change your view in Device Manager to by connection and drill down through ACPI and eventually through the appropriate [X|E|O|U]HCI USB controller, you should see your phone connected. If you expand it's node, you should see the USB interfaces it advertises. One of them should be the ADB interface. Are you seeing this fine? Are any devices showing up with warnings, errors, or unknown?

Comment: I shut down eclipse and did kill-server and then devices.  No change.  I then tried to drill down through the connection view.  I don't see any USB device associated with "XT894" that labels it as an ADB interface. At the lowest level, I see a "USB Composite Device", which contains a "USB Mass Storage Device" node and a node labeled "XT894" that has a yellow bang on it, but I can't see any errors or warnings associated with this.

Comment: If you're getting a "yellow bang" icon, your driver isn't functioning properly. I think you need to uninstall the current driver, then download and install the appropriate driver from d.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your USB setting to "Charge Only".

The "Mass Storage" setting takes control of the SD card away from the phone when plugged in.

Although I should note that even when my phone is set to "Mass Storage" it shows up... I just can't run an app through Eclipse to it.  Of course, maybe other phones are different, so I guess it's worth a try.

Comment: That seems familiar.  I think I had to do that with my old Droid2 to get it to work with this.  On the Droid4, the "connect as" field has three choices: "Mass Storage", "Media Devices", and "Camera".  There is no "Charge Only" choice.  I've tried setting to all three of these, but the device still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - look at the part about unloading the EasyTether extension. [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)
I was able to connect my samsung galaxy note 2 to macbook pro snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

ok...I made it work finally....here is my steps...

1. use USBDeview to uninstall the driver
2. unplug the usb cable
3. install KIES (download from samsung web site)
   http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-N7105RWDCOV-downloads
4. plug in the usb cable and skip obtaining driver from Windows Update
5. it will continues to install
6. open eclipse after the installation is done
7. there you go

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help somebody. I did the following for my moto x.

1. Installed Motorola device manager,which installed all the device drivers in the system.
2. Now the device was recognized , but was detected as a storage device.
3. Now,go to device manager in my case device was listed as portable devices.
4. Right click on device,update driver Software.
5. please choose Browse my computer for driver software.
6. please choose Let me pick a list from a list of device drivers on my computer
7. two options one will MTP USB Device and Other is Composite Device will be shown.
8. Install both. Thats it now you can see your device under Android Device was well in Device Manager.
9. Now Kill Adb process making sure adb process is not running also close eclipse if running.
10. Issue adb kill-server and adb start-server commands in command prompt.
11. Then after giving adb start-server a prompt will come in your device to authorize it.
12. After selecting yes, voila ur device is recognized u can check it in adb devices command as your device will be set as device.
13. Now start eclipse and u can see your device along with the emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I had this buggy error with my LG Optimus L3 phone connecting to Win7/8 machines!

**Issue:** My Android Device isn't recognized by the Eclipse ADT, why?

**Cause:** Device Driver was missing as it seemed at the end when I fixed it!

**How to Fix:**

1. Search through web (using Google) "**LG < Your_Phone_Model Number > Drivers Download**".(Ex.:- Go to About phone in your settings list **>** Model Number, for me it's LG-E400f)
2. Mostly the first few links are related to the required Device Driver download page.(Ex.:- for me I got the following [link](http://www.lg.com/au/support-mobile/lg-Optimus-L3-E400F) and for each device driver LG or most of the other vendors/manufactures have that kind of a Manuals and Drivers Page) Visit that page mentiioning about software update and drivers downloads.
3. Scroll down to the section of "**Manuals and Software Update**" and doing just the **Step 1** was enough for me, which is "Install the **USB DRIVERS** "
4. Download it(for Mac or Windows) **>** Install It **>** Check Your Eclipse ADT **>** and it should be visible under Devices tab by now

Cheers!!!
Hope this helps to someone else to clearly get to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also happen because of a faulty usb-microusb cable (which is what happened to me). I guessed that it was the cable's fault (and not the drivers) when the SD card storage wasn't even mounted when I connected the cable (but what's surprising is that the cable was still properly functioning energy-wise, since it loaded by battery correctly and the LED was lit accordingly).