# mac os x 10.6.8 and “adb devices” fails to list android devices

Tags: android, adb

I have access to a:

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.0.4)
- HTC Incredible S (Android 4.0.4)
- HTC Wildfire (Android 2.2.1)

And for the life of me I can not get any to display in adb on Mac OS X 10.6.8. I have ensured that USB debugging is turned on all devices, I do not have EasyTether installed (which seems to be a popular reason for devices not listing).

I tried removing everything I could find from the Android SDK and downloading again - but I still see nothing.

Must have spent 5 hours looking for various fixes so far.

I simply keep seeing this:

```
sh-3.2# adb devices
List of devices attached 

sh-3.2#
```

Comment: I have had problems myself and I finally found out that executing `sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server` worked for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately....          sh-3.2# sudo adb kill-server
sh-3.2# sudo adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

sh-3.2#

Comment: Did this work before? Use a different USB cable, I've also had problems with the cables.

Comment: Got 3 different cables, and tried on each one and I'm afraid nothing. I remember doing this pre-Snow Leopard in 2011 with a Google Nexus S and it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm out of ideas. Hopefully it decides to start working or someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Thanks @AlexFu! It's really frustrating this kinda stuff - mobile web apps forever :)

Comment: Facing the same issues with both Snow Leopard (Mac Mini 2.1) and Mountain Lion (Mac Mini 6.1) and my AOC Breeze MW0812 (Android 2.3). My Motorola Droid works perfectly. Have you guys noticed if the device name at least blinks in the Devices tab, under the DDMS perspective? In my case, it does. Also worth to mention is the fact that the AOC is a composite device: It has a internal (non-removable) memory card that also shows up in Finder when I activate "Mass Storage", besides the removable SD card. The Droid is a simpler device, with no such feature. Lets gather some hints on how to solve this.

Comment: Worth to mention that it used to work all the time under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Netbook.

Comment: Ejecting the SD card leads to it trying to display the running processes before vanishing. Maybe its to different issues: USB port (might need powered usb hub) and composite device incompability?

Comment: Got myself a powered usb hub and some new clues. Now I managed to get it to stay on ddms, but shows as offline. Sometimes it doesnt show up. from dmesg, when it's showing up, I get: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): AOC Tablet MW0812 0xbb4 0xc02 0x222 USBF: 202.684 Endpoint 0x83 of the USB device "rk2918 sdk" at location 0x1d113500: converting Bulk MPS from 64 to 512 (USB 2.0 Spec section 5.8.3) –

Comment: MANAGED TO DO IT! Instead of chain connecting the hubs, I decided to connect everything just to the power hub. Its quite unstable, and tend to disconnect itself out, but it worked. Also, it made the hub unstable as well. I had to disconnect it. But its a start.

Comment: I'm giving up...for now. Rooted my tablet and installed "ADBWifi". Now I can debug over Wifi. Even better!

Comment: There is a good answer: [Adb android device on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to edit the adb_usb.ini which resides in HOME/.android directory. There I added the device's vendor ID, typed "adb kill-server", "adb start-server" and it showed after adb devices. To discover the vendor ID, you can check your kernel log file under "/var/log".