# Android device not showing up in ADB, tried all other solutions on stack overflow

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

My android device can't be located using Eclipse or ADB no matter what I do. I tried everything:

- Restarting both the Windows 7 computer and the Android device.
- Checked Debugger in Developer options
- Checked run unsigned APKs
- Setting Eclipse to manually select the device to run on

I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found this website http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ and it turns out the driver I was using to connect my device to my computer was installed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x) out. as mentioned. you should add vendor id to

```
~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

then restart adb server