# audiosonic t-17b eclipse debug driver

Tags: android, driver, usb-debugging

i bought a tablet a few weeks ago: (audiosonic t-17b)
I have tried to find the drivers to debug my app from eclipse.
as far as i can tell, audiosonic don't have a website or any way for me to contact them about finding the drivers

does anyone know where I can find the drivers that I need?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the vendor ID to adb_usb.ini
the t-17b vendor ID is 0x2207

Below is the solution for Mac

From the terminal:

echo 0x2207 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
adb kill-server ; dab devices

from: [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)