# Can't connect Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device

I've been trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, looked for help everywhere I could find it, but it's not working. Here's some additional info:

- I have checked USB debugging in development options
- USB drive is working
- Reset adb gives out the following error messages:
  [2014-02-27 10:10:58 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
  [2014-02-27 10:10:58 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
  (...)

Any idea what might be the issue.

Comment: Have you installed `kies` software in your PC?

Comment: kies is not necessary. try to connect your deviec as a media device and then reset adb.

Comment: Kies is installed. In my developer options, there's no possibility to connect as a media device.

Comment: r u trying in windows or mac?

Comment: I'm using a Macintosh 10.8

Comment: if u use windows OS then install PdaNet Desktop application in ur windows and install PdaNet+ android application in ur samsung S3 mobile and then try to connect ur mobile.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. Have a new phone now (Nexus 4), it connected on the first day ... then for some reason it stopped. Might be a problem with my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Goto ddms and right click on the mobile and click reset adb ,  and also need to delete existing virtual devices, which were pretty old, and create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Execute "adb devices" in your console

If result is empty, check your cell phone 's drive is installed.

Comment: It's not listed there either, I tried following this instruction ... still not working.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x

Comment: I think you should download this model's drive software.http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2185700 This link may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To access these settings, open the Developer options in the system Settings. On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.