# Firefox App Manager doesn’t detect Intex Cloud FX

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

Recently I bought a mobile phone named "Intex Cloud FX" (it’s the first device in India running Firefox OS). I purposely bought it for developing Firefox OS apps and testing them on a real device.

The problem I face is that the Firefox App Manager can’t detect my phone for testing my local apps. I followed the instructions but couldn’t help myself.

`adb` is successfully installed on my system i.e Mac OS X 10.10.

So the question is: **How to make App Manager detect my mobile device running Firefox OS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly ensure that you have `adb` installed. Also, follow these [instructions/Troubleshooting steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager#Troubleshooting_2) given by `Mozilla`.

If that isn't working, run `adb devices` and ensure that your device is listed down. If you can't see the device listed, please follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136003/2494535), very well explained.

Now try `about:app-manager` in `Mozilla Firefox` on desktop and see if it shows whether the device is connected in the bottom left of the page. Now also, if it doesn't show, then these [special instructions for Mac OS X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Debugging/Connecting_a_Firefox_OS_device_to_the_desktop) provided by `Mozilla` is your life-saver.

These instructions helped me connecting my device running `Firefox OS` to the `app-manager` on desktop.
This summarizes how to have a perfect dev-environment for Firefox App Development and testing the same on a real device. I'll update the thread once I'll be done with a blogpost for the same.

Comment: You can also check these instructions: http://kaustavdm.in/2014/08/connect-firefox-os-spreadtrum-device-adb.html. I had written them for the same chipset that is used by the Intex Cloud FX.

Answer (score 0):

on the phone, you have to disable usb storage and screenlock. and you have to set remote debugging to adb and devtools. to do this, go to device information>more information>developer.