# Android Device Chooser not showing my device

Tags: android, device

When I try to run app on my device, the Android Device Choose is ALWAYS empty. I then remove the USB from my Mac and put it back again and the view is updated automatically by Eclipse.
Is there anything I need to do for Eclipse to add my device to the Chooser at all times?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes on mac when it can't read known manufacturer informatiom.

You need to make an entry probably

See this, it might help you

[adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)