# cordova run (in real) android device using command line?

Tags: android, cordova, command-line, device

According to the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

We can run our android project on an emulator by:

`cordova run android`  or

```
cordova emulate android
```

But how to run a project on a real android device?

thanks a lot

-EDIT-

`adb devices` list none..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can force the run on device like this

```
cordova run android --device
```

If you get an error message like "No devices found" then make sure that you have [developer mode and USB Debugging enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) on the device and also run
`adb kill-server` and then `adb devices` should list your device and `cordova run android --device` should work

For iOS you can run from macOS

```
cordova run ios --device
```

If it doesn't work, make sure you have `ios-sim` and `ios-deploy` installed and that you have your development certificate and a wildcard provisioning profile on your machine.
You can open the `.xcworkspace` file on /platforms/ios/ and Xcode will help you to create the certificates and provisioning profiles when you try to run the app.

Comment: I tried, but an error installing the .apk on the device. Do I have to set up somthing first? thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay `ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.
Error: /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/cordova/funcook/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)`

Comment: Then the problem is your computer doesn't recognize the device. If you are using windows you have to install drivers (from google or de device vendor)

Comment: I am actually using Mac OS, and I have the `htc` software included... any thoughts?

Comment: do you have the developer options activated on your phone? and the usb debuggin?

Comment: Yes to both, and `adb devices` list none.. ¿?

Comment: then that's the problem. maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x

Comment: I just needed `adb kill-server` and `adb devices`, it listed the device and `cordova run android --device` runned on the device, thanks!

Comment: For me, it wasn't enough to enable developer mode. I also had to turn on USB Debugging inside the developer settings.

Comment: @d512 thanks for the note, it happened to me the other day on a new device, I think USB Debugging was automatically enabled when you enabled Developer settings, but it isn't enabled now

Answer (score 3):

If a real device is connected to your pc and it is recognized as well, you ca just use 
`cordova run android` 
 and the app will start on your device. It worked for me.

Comment: I'm using cordova 9.0.0 and `--device` flag is needed to run in android device, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
cordova run android
```

as documented [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

That did not work for me for some reason. so what I did was copy the apk to the device. install it. and use chrome's [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) . by goint to `chrome://inspect` in chrome.

Comment: thanks for writing, the thing is that if run this command, the emulator is executed..

Comment: yes I had the same issue. I think because the target api was 19 instead of 21 (lolypop). check my updated answer for a plan B.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, running it up from the cordova directory speeds up the time it takes to run the app on the device.

If you're on Ubuntu:

```
$ cd /path/to/project/platform/android/cordova/
$ node run --device
```

For Windows:

```
> cd /path/to/project/platform/android/cordova/
> run --device
```