# How to run Cordova application?

Tags: cordova

I am a beginner in Cordova and Phonegap, can anybody guide me how to run Cordova and Phonegap application after making changes without build.phonegap. Because my index.html not run directly on web.

Is there any other way to run and build the application quickly because when I build does any small changes I have again upload the zip file on phonegap.build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova run (in real) android device using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851828/cordova-run-in-real-android-device-using-command-line)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Advice you to use ionic/ Angular : easy fast and also hybride

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Phonegap and cordova in the same way you are requesting, please visit https://phonegap.com/getstarted/ and install phonegap app for your desktop and in your device.

So for any change that you are doing, you will be able to see it in the phonegap emulator and do a final build once you are done.

Works fine with all cordova plugins !!