# Android Device Monitor not detecting device on Mac

Tags: android, macos, adb, root

I have installed Android SDK, ADB, Brew, Android Studio and when I run 'adb devices' in terminal, it is not showing my devices. I have tried with a Nexus 6 and LG G Pad 7.0 and am having the same issue. Both devices are rooted and have USB debugging enabled. They are being detected on my Win 7 machine but it is old and very slow compared to my iMac so I would like to use my mac instead. I have uninstalled/reinstalled Android Studio and also tried with Intellj and it doesn't detect it either.

UPDATE: My Nexus 6 is now being read by my Mac, but I am unable to view any threads or processes. I opened up Firefox while my device is being read and the process didn't show up in the Android Device Monitor. I have read other forums that say I have to enable androiddebugging in the Manifest.xml but I am not finding that option on the app I want to debug. I decompiled the app using APK Editor Pro on my Nexus 6 and it has a built in Manifest reader. I searched for the androiddebugging string but it did not locate it. Am I missing something? Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

Comment: Run `adb devices` and tell us what the console says.

Comment: adb output command from my LG G Pad 7.0 shows an empty list right below 'List of devices attached'