# Ionic run android not working

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

After pulling from the git repo after some time and few changes done by my colleagues, running app on my android device stopped working. I was able to run my app on my device before with usb debugging enabled, but now I get the following error after running the command `ionic run android`:

> No target specified, deploying to emulator Error: No emulator images
>   (avds) found.
>   1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/myUser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
>   2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/myUser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd HINT: For a
>   faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device
>   driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Android Studio open the AVD Manager then create AVD(if not yet created) and launch it in the emulator. Now execute the command `ionic run android` it will run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

I had the same problem and can resolve this by restart my device and my Mac.