# macOS Sierra doesn't detect USB connected Pine64 with Android

Tags: android, macos, usb

I hope someone will be able to help me. I've been trying to make it work for days.

My goal is to use the Pine64 with Android and the touchscreen to debug a game using Unity Remote. 
The board is PineA64+ 1GB, the touchscreen is the one from the Pine64 store, the SD card is the 32GB card from the store, and the Android is the 6.0.1 for LCD (http://wiki.pine64.org/index.php/Pine_A64_Software_Release#Android_6.0.1_.28LCD_Panel_Video_Output.29_.5B20170209.5D).
My computer OS is macOS Sierra (10.12.6).

I've installed the Android SDK using Android Studio (version 23.0.3 of the build-tools, since I use Android 6.0.1). When I use 'adb devices' to list the devices, it is not listed. But when I go to System Information to check if it's even detected, under Hardware > USB, nothing appears. So it seems that is not that 'adb' doesn't recognize the device, but the USB connection doesn't appear to be there; the computer doesn't detect it.

USB debugging is on, I've tried changing the USB mode between MTP and PTP, I've tried different USB ports from my laptop (if I connect my phone, Android too, it works in both), I've tried different USB cables, I've tried the different USB ports in the board (using Linux the USB ports work well, so I assume is something with Android, and not the board). I've also tried adding the vendor id in adb_usb.ini, as indicated in [adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x/7136003#7136003)

Could anyone help me? Should I use Android 5.1.1? Do I need to change some configuration, or install some app?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Just double checking that the USB cable you are using is confirmed good for data (you can connect to a different device with it and see files).

Comment: @MorrisonChang It's the same cable I use to move files to and from my phone. It's the cable that came with it (BQ Aquaris 3.5). I also tried another cable that came with an Android tablet, and check with my phone it was for data (I could copy a file from my phone to the computer).