# Android adb doesn't see android device on macOS Catalina

Tags: android, adb, macos-catalina, xiaomi

macos - 10.15.7

device - xiaomi redmi 3s

adb works fine with android emulator, but it doesn't see real device, which is has debug mode turned on.

When I connect real device via usb, I see that device is charging, but I don't see an option to choose File Transfer connection on device.

ADB connection with device works fine on my Windows PC.
How to make macos to see real device ?

Comment: Hey, have you tried restarting your computer? Or killing the `adb` server and then calling `adb devices` again.  `adb kill-server` `adb devices`

Comment: Check this out [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

Comment: OSX has no `udev` ...so this might be a case for the "genius" bar. The "USB Prober" might be able to tell which device it is, but that's it. The local firewall could eventually also prevent communication. Maybe get a device which is known to be compatible? Not closing it as duplicate, because the other one is rather dated and things may have changed (unless there's something which would solve the issue).

Comment: You can try to ask this question on this site as well: https://android.stackexchange.com/ - you might have more luck getting an answer there.

Comment: Facing same issue, guess need to downgrade to mojave!