# getting blank screen in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I have got a problem in my logcat screen and the problem is that,whenever I get error from my application I get blank screen in logcat and I am unable to look at the errors and fix them.How do I overcome this sort of issue?

here is my logcat screen:

[image]

Comment: click on v symbol. and tell me what happen

Comment: @ Dr.nik I clicked on V,D,I,W and E.All of them are showing me blank screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your ADT plugin in Eclipse and right now you are using deprecated Logcat.

```
Help > Check for Updates
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to `DDMS->Devices` and select the device that you are currently working on.

[image]

Comment: I did the same yesterday for the same problem i have got,but this didn't help me. I think,removing AVD and recreating might solve the issue along with the one you have suggested!

Comment: @Lalit Poptani In DDMS->Devices I can find my device and whenever I double click on that I get the above image

Comment: Removing AVD and re-creating it is not the exact solution I will say, better than that is to restart eclipse and try again.

Comment: @Hiral I am unable to find errors while I run it on my device as well.So I think its not the problem of AVD.

Comment: @JackDsilva I can see "Devices" tab besides Logcat Tab in your image click that and select the device that you are currently working on.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani Re-starting the eclipse is not the exact solution too.I tried it.

Comment: Actually the way you suggested is correct but it didn't work for me atleast for these.so we can try different solutions to get it to work.hence i suggested a one. even restarting eclipse should work.Thing is,i don't remember what exactly work for me for this problem yesterday,but something did.. :P

Comment: @JackDsilva try what I insisted that could surely work for you.

Comment: @Hiral  Now I have to do something to get that worked I suppose cos any of them are not working for me.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani Now I have to do something to get that worked I suppose cos any of them are not working for me.

Comment: @JackDsilva make your way to casual chat room so that we can discuss about it. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this command:---

```
adb shell
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable
```

Comment: Don't mind.Could you please tell me how to go about your solution.I am not getting that

Answer (score 0):

I run into that problem sometimes and I suggest:

- Make sure you select the "V" tag to prove that why this happened is not because there is really no errors (Since you select the "E" tag).
- Install the USB driver from the manufacturer of your device. Although you can connect the phone to PC as an USB storage device without the driver, you can't debug on the phone without it.
- In Settings->Applications->Development, check the USB debugging choice to allow you to debug on the phone.
- Make sure you have selected the proper device or emulator, not some other emulators or devices.
- Sometimes, the logcat shows nothing, even if you have finished these steps above. In this case, click the "Clear" tag(at the top right, with a RED cross), unplug the phone and plug in again.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 things to do..

1. start emulator...
2. then see devices select your avd like Windows-show view-other-android-devices...
3. then start logcat Windows-show view-other-android-logcat..that's it and it will do..

But First you should see the emulator in devices..

If you can't then in devices click down arrow near camera icon and click on reset adb.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in the Android Debug Monitor today. The reason this happened to me was because I had set the "maximum number of logcat messages to buffer" under Preferences/Android/LogCat to some very large amount like 50000000000. If you have played with this setting try setting it lower to like 5000. Once I configured mine back down to 50000 I started seeing messages come through LogCat again. You may have to restart things like the Android Debug Monitor, adb, the computer, the emulator, or the phone. At one point or another I tried all of those. Also you should see an error message when you try to configure this setting back to default. I believe it was a Java Null pointer or something. You can safely ignore the message and just check that the configuration worked when you go back into the Debug monitor. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been asked long before, I am answering for others who might stumble upon this trouble.

In Mars, eclipse 4.5 and linux using GTK 3, if Android Logcat display is missing, add the following in eclipse.ini before `--launcher.appendVmargs`

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

May also refer these posts.
[Logcat show invisible messages in Eclipse Mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403672/logcat-show-invisible-messages-in-eclipse-mars)
[Eclipse GUI broken](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200053)