# Logcat show invisible messages in Eclipse Mars

Tags: linux, eclipse, debian, logcat

My PC running on Debian Jessie & Logcat's messages are all invisible on eclipse Mars. I tried a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336123/android-logcat-messages-invisible-in-eclipse), but no help. What to do now?

[image: Screenshot]

**---------- UPDATE ----------**

I tried the followings:

1. Change logcat/ddms's metadata settings in com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs file.
2. Don't use GTK3 by export SWT_GTK3=0

But both failed to fix the situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem (Eclipse Mars on Arch Linux) and it turned out to be a GTK issue.
The solution was to add the following two lines

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

in eclipse.ini right before the

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

line, as explained in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=200053
Note that the location of eclipse.ini is distro specific (in my case it was under /usr/lib/eclipse) and multiple copies of the file in different directories can override the same setting, so make sure you are adding the lines in the right place.

Comment: This did not work for me @RyanB. Did you also edit anything besides this?

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho No, just added above 2 lines to eclipse.ini. Your problem may not be the same root as mine. Let try another approaches mentioned around here.

Comment: @RyanB thanks for the comment, but I've already solved and left my config in a separate answer :)

Comment: I was struggling for several hours with this issue. That worked for me, after all. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here! Arch linux with eclipse-java 4.5.0-3

My solution was this reply:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28856904/2398244

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error  
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false  
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true  
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=169
logcat.view.colsize.Level=54
logcat.view.colsize.PID=54
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=198
logcat.view.colsize.Text=619
logcat.view.colsize.Time=182
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you Charlie S your advice, I did it.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with GTK and Eclipse Mars. Try to set the SWT_GTK3 environment variable to 0 before launching eclipse:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on eclipse MARS, ubuntu14.04 and i solved the problem by modifying the file.

/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs

you should close the eclipse and paste following code.

```
ddms.logcat.auotmonitor.level=error
ddms.logcat.automonitor=false
ddms.logcat.automonitor.userprompt=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
logcat.view.colsize.Application=200
logcat.view.colsize.Level=70
logcat.view.colsize.PID=50
logcat.view.colsize.TID=50
logcat.view.colsize.Tag=170
logcat.view.colsize.Text=300
logcat.view.colsize.Time=140
```

Then restart the eclipse.
You could adjust by dragging the section of the Logcat as your prefer.

Comment: I did that, but it also doesn't work. I think this is a bug of eclipse mars since logcat & ddms are ok on older eclipse versions. Never mind, i'm now switching to android studio & everything is fine atm.